# RxJava error handling

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have a method that creates and merges two `Observable<T>`'s.

```
private Observable<String> getData() {

    Observable<String> observable1 = Observable.just("Just string")
            .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Observable<String> observable2 = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            subscriber.onError(new Exception("Oops!"));
        }
    });

    Observable<String> merged = observable1.mergeWith(observable2);

    return merged;        
}
```

The problem is that the error in the `observable2` emitted earlier than the data in the `observable1`.

```
getData().subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.d("rx", "onCompleted");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.d("rx", "onError: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                Log.d("rx", "onNext: " + s);
            }
        });
```

`observable2` emitted optional data and errors from `observable2`must not terminate emission, but on the other hand, I want to handle all errors and data in a single observer. Can I return this error after the result from the `observable1`? Is that possible?

Expect results:

```
onNext: Just string
onError: Oops!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need something like `Observable.mergeDelayError()`.

It applies a `merge` operation but if some of the Observables call `onError`, it doesn't stop right away but captures the error(s).

Once all other Observables have gracefully completed, the error(s) is(are) propagated, potentially combined into a single `CompositeException`.

Comment: You should probably elaborate some more on why that's the case

Comment: Maybe this would be a good explanation of Observable.mergeDelayError(): https://github.com/dawidgdanski/rx-java-handies/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/dawidgdanski/sample/rx/observable/MergeContractTest.java#L155